# How to reload number without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, reload

My .php is reading some variables from pos.txt and I need to show them live, without refreshing the page. I've used `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">`, but it's annoying. I've read something about ajax, but I can't really understand how it works.

```
$line = file_get_contents('pos.txt');
list($date, $time, $x, $y, $z) = explode(' ', $line);
```

Answer (score 2):

For this you have to use AJAX. You have to learn this http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp.
Once you learn it you will use it allways.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a ajax call from your display page to your php file.

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
{
   if (ajax.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
      var response = ajax.responseText;
     // Here is your response
   }
}
ajax.open("POST", "request/path/response.php");
ajax.send(any_data);
```

[Details](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use jquery ajax:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You want to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "pos.txt",
}).done(function(data) {
    var split = data.split(' ');
    var date = split[0];
    var time = split[1];
    var x = split[2];
    var y = split[3];
    var z = split[4];
    //then insert these variables into the elements you need
    $('#date').val(date);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: "[_YOUR_URL_]/post.txt",
}).done(function(data) {
    $("#some_id").val(date.find("some data").text);
});
```

The code of above obvisouly won't work, but the code you will use can be that simple.
And as stated above once you go ajax you wont go back.

Using the jQuery wrapper makes the ajax bunches easier.  You will want to spend an hour or two reading about it as well as looking at various samples

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
{
   if (ajax.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
      var response = ajax.responseText;
     document.getElementById('get-data').innerHtml = response;
   }
}
ajax.open("GET", "pos.txt");
ajax.send(any_data);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="get-data">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```